# Question on the choice of boundary in the CUSUM test when we make some resampling

Tags: econometrics, finance, applied-econometrics, statistics, probability

**Question on the choice of boundary in the CUSUM test when we make some resampling**

We are considering to make a CUSUM test for some economical time series $=(_1,..,x_n)$. Suppose  contains many noises which need to be removed in some ways. Simply speaking, the CUSUM test considers the empirical process,

$W_n = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)$

and check if it hits the boundary corresponding to the Brownian bridge. In practice, for execution of the CUSUM test, we utilize an R package, `strucchange`. Now we have a question. The question is related to the scaling of boundary since we are considering to make a resampling or filtering raw data, and perform a CUSUM test, again.

Question is as follows: **Do we need to make any rescaling the boundary when we make a filtering data?** For instance, should we need to multiply the original boundary by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ (m: sample length)? Since we are using the open source R package, `strucchange` in performing the CUSUM test, it is not so clear if we need to take care of such a rescaling factor of the boundary function.